# Where are configured the folders icons in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

Something happened to my thunderbird profile: now every folder in the folder three pane on the left has the same standard yellow folder icon.

I mean that the special icons for INBOX, Trash etc. are missing.

I've tried to temporarily rename the profile folder, then restarting Thunderbird, now all the special icons are back again.

So the problem appear to be in the profile folder.

I don't want to delete my profile folder cause it contain all my emails.... :-(

any idea?

## Edit

I forget to mention the version of thunderbird I'm using: Earlybird v.22.0a2.

As a side note, if I delete the profile and let thunderbird recreate a new one, all the special folders icons (INBOX, Sent Items, Trash etc) on he left pane tree are recreated and showing fine.
But... as I've been asking in my original question, I would like to avoid recreating the whole mail archive, since I've tons of mails...

## >>> SOLVED! <<<

Finally I was able to determine the offending plugin!
It was Remove Duplicate Messages (Alternate) v0.3.7
Disabling it and installing Remove Duplicate Messages (original) v0.1.13 from the following link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/remove-duplicate-messages/
solved the problem for me!

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case 'remove duplicate messages (alternate)', 'toolbar buttons 1.0' and 'color folders 1.0' addons had to be disabled to get the (non-yellow) folder icons back in tb v24. the two latter were running good on tb v23 with 'addon compatibilty check disabled'

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like user-error, rather than a bug.

The left pane lets you pick what part of a profile. It can collapse or grow as you select or deselect; sounds like you de-selected.

BTW, I think this question belongs on [Super-User.](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: I'm referring to the special icons that represent special folders in thunderbird, as for example the recycle bin icon for the trash folder and so on.

Comment: I know. I use TB daily. BTW, it has many versions and they differ - you never specified which one!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this behavior!  So far, this is the only place where I've seen it mentioned.  In my case the bug was appearing in the new Thunderbird v24.0 regular release, and it was caused by the JunQuilla v1.0.2 extension.  The developer has released v1.0.3 on the AMO site to address the problem.  Currently the "Check for Updates" feature in TB is not finding this version, but you can download it direct from the AMO page for the extension (click the "View other versions" link).

Hope this helps!

(Peter)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (after updating from TB 17 to 24.0.1). It resolved after updating "Compact Header" and "Extra folder columns" add ons.